# set python submodule name in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have a Python package with this structure:

```
folder/
    __init__.py
    subfolder_a/
        __init__.py
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
    subfolder_b/
        __init__.py
setup.py
```

My setup.py is

```
setup(
    name=folder,
    packages=[folder, folder.subfolder_a, folder.subfolder_b],
)
```

`script_1.py` call `script_2.py` as `from subfolder_a import script_2` and I cannot change this code.

Using my code I have an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named subfolder_a`.
Is there a way in `setup.py` to rename a package?

Comment: "I cannot change this code.": why not? The import is definitely incorrect, so that should be changed.

Comment: Note that naming modules inside a package `script_.py` can be very confusing. `module_?.py`, even for an example, would be a lot better.

Comment: `from . import script_2` in `script_1.py` would be better, since the two modules are at the same level inside the (sub)package.

Comment: @9769953 I know! :( I cannot change it because it is an automatically generated code

Comment: Then the generator should be fixed. Sorry, but if the actual code can't be fixed, then this is simply broken code. Any workaround I can think of is not something I will put here, since that will just make things worse at the end of the day.